# Is @realDonaldTrump a parody account?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, social-media

Is the Twitter account [@realDonaldTrump](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump) a parody account, or is it actually controlled by Donald Trump?

Comment: [Poe's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law): *"it is impossible to create a parody of extreme views so obviously exaggerated that it cannot be mistaken by some readers or viewers as a sincere expression of the parodied views"*. This also applies in reverse.

Comment: There's a reason for the "verified" check.

Comment: Why not both? :)

Answer (score 21):

That's his real account.  It is linked from his [campaign website](https://www.donaldjtrump.com/).

It is also listed as his account by media sites.  E.g. [Newsweek](http://www.newsweek.com/how-vulnerable-trumps-twitter-account-hacking-541796).

Comment: Worth adding that a statistical analysis of that accounts activity supports that tweets sent from Android are from him and tweets from IPhone are from his staffers. http://varianceexplained.org/r/trump-tweets/

Comment: @casey Do we know which the [Chinese hoax claim](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36330/did-donald-trump-say-that-global-warming-was-a-hoax-invented-by-the-chinese/) was made from?

Comment: @ChemicalEngineer that was via the Twitter website. The iPhone/Android split is a more recent thing but it def fits his post style.

Answer (score 13):

Twitter places a "verified" checkmark on accounts that have gone through a review process and verified to be who they claim to be. @realDonaldTrump possesses this verification.

You'll also find major media organizations [citing this account](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/14/us/politics/john-lewis-donald-trump.html) as his.

[image: Verified account]

Comment: > You'll also find major media organizations citing this account as his. - yes but everyone knows that the mainstream media especially the financially failing new york times lie about everything. So sad. Fake news.

Comment: This answer certainly reads differently in light of current Twitter news…

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure, but based on the following, it seems a valid account:

- **direct name account redirection**: @donaldtrump redirects to @realDonaldTrump
- **followers**: almost 20M
- **[verified account](https://support.twitter.com/articles/119135) sign**: it's there (blue check near the name)